# About the identity $1=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)$

Tags: generating-functions

I'm learning about generating function. I have trouble understanding why

$$1=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots),$$

if in the second parenthesis it stop at any $k\in\mathbb N, x^k$ then an additional term $(-x)(x^k)$ will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm probably missing something here, but:

If $$s= 1+\underbrace{x+x^2+x^3+\cdots}$$ then  $$xs= \underbrace{x+x^2+x^3+\cdots}$$

so $$ s-sx = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Formal Power Series**

In the context of [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series), numerical convergence is not the main concern. Two series are considered close if the coefficients of all terms of degree less than or equal to $n$ are equal; the greater the $n$, the closer they are. Thus, as a formal power series,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}1-x^n\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$
In this case, the series actually does converge numerically for $|x|\lt1$, but this is not important for a formal power series.

---

**Cauchy Product Formula**

The product of two formal power series can be evaluated using the [Cauchy Product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). The Cauchy Product Formula also gives
$$
(1-x)\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

When talking about generating functions, the intuition is to treat $x$ as a number "very close to $0$", so that $x^n$ becomes smaller and smaller as $n$ gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the identity $$2=2^0+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+\cdots$$
If you stop the series at any $k\in \mathbb{N}$, you don't get $2$, but rather $2-2^{-k}$.  This extra term only appears when we terminate the series at a finite step, and vanishes as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: Just multiply the two factors, you will see all terms will be canceled except 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop at $x^{n - 1}$, the left side will read $1 - x^n$ which you can verify by multiplying it out.

Your identity only holds for $-1 < x < 1$. When that is true, $x^n = 0$ for large n.